# IQueryable vs IEnumerable: is IQueryable always better and faster?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, iqueryable

1. If the `IQueryable` interface performs the query expression in the server rather than fetching all records like `IEnumerable`, why is `IQueryable` not replaced by `IEnumerable` where it can be faster and more efficient?
2. `DBSet<T>` has two flavors of `Where` (`IQueryable` and `IEnumerable`). Is there a way to call the `IEnumerable` version because the `IQueryable` is called by default, without calling `ToList()`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> 1. If the `IQueryable` perform the query Expression in the server rather
>      than fetching  all records like `IEnumerable`, why `IQueryable` not
>      replaced by `IEnumerable` where it can be faster and more efficient?

`IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` represent two different things. Think of a `IQueryable` as a "question", it does not have any results itself. A `IEnumerable` is an "answer", it only has data connected to it but you can't tell what generated that data.

It is not that a `IQueryable` is "faster" per say, it just allows you to put your filtering and projections in to the "question" you ask to the SQL server and let it return only the answers it needs to (In the form of a `IEnumerable` by calling `.ToList()` or similar).

If you only use a `IEnumerable` the only question you can ask is "Give me everything you know" then on the answer it gives you you perform your filtering and projections. That is why `IQueryable` is considered faster, because there is a lot less data that needs to be processed because you where able to ask a more specific question to the server.

The reason `IQueryable` has not replaced `IEnumerable` everywhere is because the thing you are asking a question has to be able to understand the question you are asking it. It takes a lot of work to be able to parse every possible thing you could ask it to filter or project on so most implementations [limit themselves to only common things they know they need to be able to answer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550(v=vs.110).aspx). For example in Entity Framework when you ask a question it does not understand how to handle you will get a error that says something similar to *"Specified method is not supported"* when you try to get a `IEnumerable` (an answer) from the `IQueryable`.

> 2. `DBSet<T>` has two flavors of `Where` (`IQueryable` and `IEnumerable`).
>      is there a way to call the `IEnumerable` version because the
>      `IQueryable` is called by default, without calling `ToList()`?

The class `DBSet<T>` has no [Where method on it at all](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx). The two `Where` functions come from two extension methods, [`Enumerable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Queryable.Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.where(v=vs.110).aspx). You can force it to use the Enumerable overload by casting the object to a `IEnumerable<T>` before you call the extension method. However do remember, `Queryable.Where` filters the question, `Enumerable.Where` only filters the result.

It is wasteful to ask for results from the server to then just throw them away, so I would not recommend doing this.

Comment: Your example (question and answer) is great, as I've understood from it, the `IQueryable` is not useful until I convert it to an `IEnumerable` list to get the desirable answer

Comment: So after i did all my related things with IQueryable i convert it to an Enumerable list and get the result right?